# PortScannerError 'nmap program not found in path' (but it is in path)

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, nmap

I am getting an error that nmap is not found in my PATH (using python-nmap). However, it is in my PATH.

Nmap works when I execute my script in Python, but when I use pyinstaller to freeze the code to a .exe file, I get this error when I try to run my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "utils\map_network.py", line 7, in scan_network
  File "site-packages\nmap\nmap.py", line 131, in __init__
PortScannerError: 'nmap program was not found in path. PATH is : 

C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\;
C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\;
C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;
C:\\windows\\system32;C:\\windows;
C:\\windows\\System32\\Wbem;
C:\\windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;
C:\\Python27\\;
C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\;
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;
C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;
C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;

C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nmap;

C:\\Users\\sillico\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;
C:\\Users\\sillico\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\cmd'
```

As you can see, I have Nmap in my PATH. Any thoughts?

Comment: Probably `subprocess.Popen` is failing. I see in the source that it only redirects `stdout`, leaving stdin and stderr as the current values. That's potentially a problem in Windows 7 if you're freezing this as a non-console application, since the proces may inherit invalid console handle values in its standard handles. In that case, a workaround is to set the process standard handles to `NULL` at startup.

Comment: For example: `import ctypes;` `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True);` `for h in (-10, -11, -12): kernel32.SetStdHandle(h, None)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get around this error by upgrading to Python 3.5. Was using Python 2.7.